# Why does Spark read data even no actions are called?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a confusion of the lazy load on Spark while using spark.read.json.

I have the following code:

```py
df_location_user_profile = [
    f"hdfs://hdfs_cluster:8020/data/*/*"
]
df_json = spark.read.json(json_data_files)
```

While the JSON data on HDFS is partitioned by year and month (year=yyyy, month=mm) and I want to retrieve all data of that dataset.
For this code block, I only read data from the defined location and there are no actions is executed. But I found on the Spark UI the following stage with giant input data.
[image: load JSON data job]
[image: load JSON data stage]

As I understand, the lazy load fashion of Spark will not read data until an action is called. Then this makes me confused.

After that, I call the `count()` action then the new stage is created and Spark read data again.

[image: counting stage]

My question is why does Spark read data when no action is called (on the first job, stage)? How can I optimize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing a pass to evaluate the schema as it was not supplied. Aka infer schema.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can I skip this step?
Or how can I optimize the performance of reading JSON on HDFS?

Comment: If you provide the schema yourself. See https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-json-with-schema/. You can also supply a subset afaicr.